# Process lines between patterns

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to extract some information from a very huge document. The file follows this pattern:

```
'>Title 1'

0 200, >name [numbers&letters]

1 200, >name [numbers&letters] 

2 200, >name [numbers&letters]

'>Title 2'

0 200, >name [numbers&letters]

1 200, >name [numbers&letters] 

...

'>Title 600.000'
```

For each group of lines between `Title`, I need to print 3 tab-separated columns

- the number of lines between each `Title`
- the `name`
- the number on the 2nd column of the first line in the group (first lines always starts with `0`) – in the example the number is `200`

I'm trying with Bash and awk/sed, but I'm not able to define a kind of loop for this task. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the expected output? it can be done by `awk`, but not possible without knowing exactly what is needed. Also if you have tried anything, show us :)

Comment: Output will be row with the 3 values in columns (tab separeted)

Comment: well any of the below answers would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but should be close:

```
awk -F'[ ,>]+' '
/^.>/ {
    if (count != "") { printf "%s %d %d\n", name, number, count }
    count = 0
    name = number = ""
    next
} 
NF {
    if (++count == 1) { number = $2; name = $3 }
}
END {
    if (count != "") { printf "%s %d %d\n", name, number, count }
}
' file
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but with some modifications :) 

awk '
/^>/ {
    if (count != "") { printf "%s %d %d\n", name, number, count }
    count = 0
    name = number = ""
    next
} 
NF {
    if (++count == 1) { number = $2; name = $3 }
}
END {
    if (count != "") { printf "%s %d %d\n", name, number, count }
}
' $1

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^.>/{t=$0;next} NF{a[t]++} $1=="0"{b[t]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i]}' file
```

Comment: if the titles are uniq, you don't need to store them in an array, can print them part by part using `printf` or print at one shot (by printing the last title's data when you get the next title )